# Rails 4, Polymer and Zurb Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, polymer

I'm trying to integrate Polymer components into my Rails 4 app that is already integrated with zurb foundation 5.

I have followed the instructions for the polymer-rails && polymer-paper-rails gems and included require paper-button/paper-button into my application.html.erb

My buttons.haml file looks like this:

```
%paper-button= "Flat Button"
```

What is however displayed on the ui,is Flat Button plain text and not a Polymer Flat Button.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a known issue with these Gems(Polymer and Foundation) not functioning well together?

UPDATE:

After a long struggle, I have managed to get this GEM to run without any notice/error in the Google Chrome Console. Firefox is still not happy however. It does seem to be a different issue now, since I've added platform.js into the pre-compiler. After adding platform.js to the pre-compiler, components have disappeared from the UI completely (As if no component code exists), and this only happens in Firefox.

See below a screenshot of Firebug:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem suggests you are not loading `platform.js` (or it's not working properly) as it provides polyfills for WebComponent technology that's only native on Chrome today.

Comment: Hi @ScottMiles. Thanks for your response. If this is the case then I'm really not sure why it would not work properly... I have followed the instructions on Git Hub to the letter and can confirm that platform.js is required in my manifest file.